# queries in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have to fetch those records where cityname like'zipcode' where zipcode is variable and apply conditions

```
var zipcd = (from u in db.ZipCodes1
             where u.CityName.Contains(zipcode) && u.CityType == "D"
             select u).ToList().Select(u => new Viewsearch
                                            {
                                              Zipcode = u.ZIPCode,
                                              CityName = u.CityName,
                                              stateabbr = u.StateAbbr    
                                            }).Distinct();

Viewsearch vs = (Viewsearch)zipcd;

if (zipcd.Count() > 1)
{
  locations = "United States;" + vs.stateabbr + ";" + vs.CityName;
}
else if (locations == "") 
{
  locations = "United States;" + vs.stateabbr + ";" + vs.CityName;
}
else
{
  locations = "United States;" + vs.stateabbr + ";" + vs.CityName + "," + locations;
}
if (zipcd.Count() > 3) is greater than 3
{
  locations = locations.Replace(locations, "," + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted?  It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: it is giving error Unable to cast object of type '<DistinctIterator>d__81`1[ITClassifieds.Models.Viewsearch]' to type 'ITClassifieds.Models.Viewsearch'. and when casting from number value must be less than infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distinct at the end of your query uses `IEqualityComparer`, and I'm guessing you haven't defined one for `Viewsearch`.  It would look something like this:

```
public class ViewsearchComparer : IEqualityComparer<Viewsearch>
{
    public bool Equals(Viewsearch vs1, Viewsearch vs2)
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Viewsearch vs)
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

After you have that defined, you pass it into your distinct call:

```
.Select(u => new Viewsearch
{
    Zipcode = u.ZIPCode,
    CityName = u.CityName,
    Stateabbr = u.StateAbbr    
})
.Distinct(new ViewsearchComparer());
```

Comment: This wouldn't cause the OP's problems - the default equality comparer can still compare objects. However, the type of the collection will be `IQueryable<ViewSearch>` or something rather than that of a single element, which is causing the error.

Comment: @Tomas Lycken: Did you see the error that he indicated in his comment though?`<DistinctIterator>d__81'1[ITClassifieds.Models.Viewsearch]' to type 'ITClassifieds.Models.Viewsearch`.  I thought those were due to problems with the default comparer.  I'd be curious to know if this would work or now.

Comment: @Tomas Lycken: Yeah, no I think you're right--after reading your answer the cast without the `FirstOrDefault()` makes sense.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're casting an *iterator* to the type of a *single element* on the line
 `ViewSearch vs = (ViewSearch)zipcd`.

If you want `vs` to be a single object, you must call `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` on your collection:

```
ViewSearch vs = zipcd.First(); // Throws if there are no elements
ViewSearch vs = zipcd.FirstOrDefault(); // null if there are no elements
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest that you download and use the lovely [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) not only to run your LINQ queries first but also to learn from it (has a lot of samples that you can run right form there, no more config needed)

for your question:

```
var zipcd = (
         from u in db.ZipCodes1
         where u.CityName.Contains(zipcode) && u.CityType == "D"
         select new Viewsearch
         {
             Zipcode = u.ZIPCode,
             CityName = u.CityName,
             stateabbr = u.StateAbbr    
          }).Distinct().ToList();
```

As you can see the query works:

[image]